# Filling SRTM 1-arc second V4 voids using SRTM 1-arc second V3 with different resolution

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator, resolution, srtm, void

I want to fill voids in the SRTM 1-arc second V4 (resolution 30m) DEM for Europe. Is it possible to directly fill the voids using SRTM 1-arc second V3 (resolution 90m) without resampling it to 30m resolution?

Comment: Both QGIS and ArcGIS have something called 'Raster Calculator' (possibly other GIS packages too) and both of them can do conditional calculations but their syntax is very different.  Please specify your software.

Comment: Please take the 2-minute [Tour] that is designed to introduce all users to the site and its protocols.  If your earlier question has not been answered then we need you to edit it to try and provide enough details to attract a potential answerer.  You should never simply ask the question again to try and draw attention to it.

Comment: @PolyGeo I didn't think about it being a duplicate as I don't want to resample to a 30m DEM in this case. But of course I'll take the tour, thanks.

Comment: @MappaGnosis I'm using QGIS and couldn't find any conditional statements so far. I heard about a plugin called RasterCalc but I didn't manage to install it.

Comment: You don't need to install a new plugin.  You just need to get the syntax right. Do a search on this forum 'QGIS raster calculator conditional' and you will find other questions asking the same thing.  A search on the web will also answer this question e.g.: https://losetposet.wordpress.com/2015/01/15/if-statement-in-qgis-raster-calculator/

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain why you think it is not a duplicate, to let us know whether you are using QGIS or something else, and to address any other requests for clarifications that may arise.